# JSON object unable to pass with jQuery Ajax and Java

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm generating a JSON Object using jQuery and tried to pass this with jQuery Ajax. But while with console.log the var i'm getting the proper data in JSON Object format and while passing the var as data i'm getting exception as below.

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data
```

But i tried to pass the data by copying from console.log and hardcoded as

```
 data: '{"bookSeriesTitle":"test","bookEdition":"test","bookAuthorPrimary":"test","bookEditor":"test"}'
```

its working fine..here is my Jquery ajax code:

```
console.log("'" + result + "'");
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "saveMe", 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: "'" + result + "'" ,         
            //data: '{"bookSeriesTitle":"test","bookEdition":"test","bookAuthorPrimary":"test","bookEditor":"test"}', 
            contentType: 'application/json',
            mimeType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) { 
                alert("success");
            },
            error:function(data,status,er) { 
                alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
            }
        });
```

Can anyone please let me know how can i fix this issue...Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass data in object you shouldn't enclose `{` and `}` in `'` or `"`. If you pass like that it will be a string.

Pass data as,

```
data: {
        //Your data
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON.stringify function:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: "saveMe", 
        type: 'POST', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        data: JSON.stringify(result),          
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) { 
            alert("success");
        },
        error:function(data,status,er) { 
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
        }
});
```

Comment: i have modified  data: JSON.stringify(result),     but still i'm getting the same exception..